# docker-compose refused connection to other container in same network

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

Maybe someone had problem like I have.

I have two .NET Core services in different containers from host both are working, but then I try request from "document_core" to "documentdata" getting error: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:60100)`

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, docker desktop and Windows containers.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  document_core:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}documentcore
    ports:
      - "60010:80"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Document_Core\Dockerfile

  documentdata:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}documentdata
    ports:
      - "60100:80"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DocumentData\Dockerfile
    environment:
      - api_endpoint=http://document_core
    depends_on:
      - document_core
```

My network details:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "dockercompose15375538289555251567_default",
        "Id": "2d31c522498ff6c0fa52431b5516caf4cdec0cff8e9d744173a970752ef8449b",
        "Created": "2023-10-26T13:02:27.997627+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "nat",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "windows",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.23.128.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.128.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0ac0a5de8714870234e4ec5d236c6b6682336a17cf5f425da6e20751e1edb551": {
                "Name": "Document_Core",
                "EndpointID": "724c7913143fd3fed0017fbfa70b78a0dbc4ceb7df9b9ec9f3afb86b7790844c",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:58:a3:3c",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.142.210/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a5a345031804135f7144e87ecb4a74e667d53223086233309ea50ee2f9ac1b36": {
                "Name": "DocumentData",
                "EndpointID": "5d5cdabc023599743a838a1b087948bf422c83c7a81512c5304777a4d4de6b88",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:58:aa:7e",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.134.205/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "FAE708C9-5255-4257-8D67-081BBAD577BD"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "dockercompose15375538289555251567",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.22.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: _"but then I try request from "document_core" to "documentdata" getting error"_ - please show the code which tries to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (**localhost**:60100)

For app running in the `document_core` container `localhost` will be the container itself which obviously does not have the `documentdata` running on 60100 port. You can try using the second container name (i.e. something like `documentdata:80`) or if your host OS (the one running the docker itself) is Windows you can use `host.docker.internal` to reach outside the container i.e. `host.docker.internal:60100` (not sure about out of the box support on Linux but there are some [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62431165/2501279)).

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75266705/2501279).

Comment: @Justinas was glad to help!