# How does Docker read config from .NET application? and which config get used in the application if Docker is enabled?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-8

I have setup Docker with an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application using Docker compose. There are two containers according to my `compose.yaml`, one is for the MySQL database (volume) and one for server. I managed to setup both containers and be able to interact with the database in the Docker volume using `docker exec`. The data get loaded from the `.sql` which lived in local directory.

However, the problem I face at the moment is I can't connect my application to the database in the Docker.

PS: my `Dockerfile` is the default one from running `docker init`.

`compose.yaml`

```
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports: 
       - 3306:3306
    volumes:
       - ./sql-script:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
       - datafiles:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_USER: ${USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB}
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 
    environment:
      - DBHOST=database
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    restart: always
    develop:
        watch:
         - action: rebuild
           path: .
volumes:
  datafiles:
```

`Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<myDatabaseContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDatabase") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'myDatabase' not found.")));
```

According to my understanding, I'm still not sure about how Docker read application config files.

1. `launchSettings.json` - this file will work only in Development mode and directly related to the play button in Visual Studio. In my case, this file can be ignored.
2. `appsettings.json` - still not sure about this one, if it get call or not?
3. `appsettings.Development.json` - This is what my `compose.yaml` called. I assume that when I define `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`, this is the file that get loaded.

At the moment, I have defined my `connectionStrings` inside `appsettings.json` which looks like this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "myDatabase" : "Server=localhost,3306; Database=myDb; User=admin; Password=pass;"
}
```

Please correct if I'm wrong, if I set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` in the `compose.yaml`, does this means all the app config file will get read from `appsettings.Devlopment.json` and NOT from `appsettings.json`.

Second question: when the `appsettings.json` will get called and not `appsettings.Development.json`? and where do I define the instruction for it to call different config file?

Comment: appsettings.json is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on the config first:

> How does Docker read config from .NET application?

Docker does not read config from .NET application, .NET application reads config based on how configuration providers are set up.

As [per docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#default-application-configuration-sources) default in your case would be:

> The initialized `WebApplicationBuilder` (`builder`) provides default configuration for the app in the following order, from highest to lowest priority:
>
> 1. Command-line arguments using the Command-line configuration provider.
> 2. Non-prefixed environment variables using the Non-prefixed environment variables configuration provider.
> 3. User secrets when the app runs in the `Development` environment.
> 4. `appsettings.{Environment}.json` using the JSON configuration provider. For example, `appsettings.Production.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`.
> 5. `appsettings.json` using the JSON configuration provider.
> 6. A fallback to the host configuration.

i.e. all configuration sources are added hierarchically (based on the environment), so this:

> if I set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` in the `compose.yaml`, does this means all the app config file will get read from `appsettings.Devlopment.json` and NOT from `appsettings.json`.

is not fully correct, in case of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` both files will be read (if both are present in the container), `appsettings.Devlopment.json` will have higher precedence, i.e. if some key is present in both the one from `appsettings.Devlopment.json` will be used.

As for your specific issue, in the following:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "myDatabase" : "Server=localhost ..."
}
```

`localhost` will mean the container with application itself, which obviously does not have the database installed (it is in separate container, note that this is quite common error - for example: [docker-compose refused connection to other container in same network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77366070/2501279)).

Change your connection string for example to something like:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
     "myDatabase" : "Server=database;Port=3306; Database=myDb; User=admin; Password=pass;"
}
```

Note that this is your compose file specific so it would be arguably better to specify this setting in the compose file itself via environment variables (since the higher precedence than JSON config files, note that `:` should be substituted with double underscore (`__`) - see the linked previously doc):

```
server:
  #...
  environment:
    - ConnectionStrings__myDatabase='Server=database;Port=3306; Database=myDb; User=admin; Password=pass;'
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  #...
```

Comment: But If I put all connection strings in `compose.yaml` then in my `Program.cs`, How do I update the connection to the DB? Because at the moment it read from `appsettings.json` which it look for `ConnectionStrings` there.

Comment: @BrianNgamsom please reread the answer. You read connection string from settings. Unless you have cleared configuration sources manually you can use different sources for connection string depending on the environment. For docker compose - from environment variable, for local development - from appsettings.

Answer (score 0):

Your database server runs on the host named `database` as you define in the environment variable `DBHOST`, but in you connection string you try to connect to `localhost`. Change you ConnectionString and it should work

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
     "myDatabase" : "Server=database,3306; Database=myDb; User=admin; Password=pass;"
}
```