# Address not available after HttpRequest in Docker Container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, keycloak, minimal-apis

So this is my setup:

- .NET Minimal APIs running in a Docker Container
- Keycloak running in a Docker Container

In the development environment of my minimal-Api I can make a Http Request against the Keycloack Container to get an AccessToken

After running my api in a Docker Container the request isn't working anymore.
After the making the request I get the Error:

> "Address not available (localhost:8080)"

This is how I do the Request in the Api:

this is the Dockerfile to build the Image for the minimal Api:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "projectName.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost):

> In computer networking, localhost is a hostname that refers to the current computer used to access it. The name localhost is reserved for loopback purposes.

When you will run your app in the docker container `localhost` will mean the container itself, not the host machine, and your container obviously does not have docker installed. If you are running on Windows then you can use `host.docker.internal` to reach outside the container i.e. `host.docker.internal:8080` (maybe it is supported on other systems but can't verify this now). If this does work you can try getting acquainted with [docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/) (and [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/)) and leveraging it.

Notes and see also:

1. Since .NET 8 [the default ASP.NET Core port configured in .NET container images has been updated from port 80 to 8080.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port) so if you will upgrade then you will need to act accordingly
2. [docker-compose refused connection to other container in same network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77366070/2501279)
3. Common way to set up local infrastructure for testing is to use docker compose, for example [How to connect an ASP.NET backend to a postgres database inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75266654/2501279)

Comment: So this kinda helped me. 
Yes its not the localhost.
Better solution is to look into the Ip-Address which is given to the container by docker.

you can do it by using:
docker inspect <container-name/id>

look for the ip Address

Comment: @Trixtor was glad to help! Yes, that's what I meant by leveraging docker networking. You also can try using the container name to connect (since they are in the same network) - `container-name:port-in-container`. P.S. you can upvote the answers too ;)

Comment: Strom thx for your time and very good answer. Now everything works smooth and I also learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Docker Compose File

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  new-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    image: test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "53084:80"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak
      - db
    networks:
      - new-network

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.6
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    command: [ 'start-dev' ]
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"

    networks:
      - new-network

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-secret-pw
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: keycloak
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

    networks:
      - new-network
```

And this is the BaseURL to Call the keycloak container from the api:

```
http://keycloak:8080
```